# Error al añadir un for dentro de un array con un tipo de datos TaxOutputType facturación electrónica españa

Tags: c#

resulta que estoy construyendo el XML para presentar en España una factura electrónica. Yo cojo una factura electrónica de ejemplo y la copio idénticamente, hasta ahí todo bien, sin embargo a la hora de añadirle un for dentro el Visual Studio no me deja y da error. No se como asignarle un valor cargado dinámicamente.

[image: Formato funcionando]

Y aquí en la segunda imagen vemos el error

[image: Error en el Visual Studio con el for]

Ójala me puedan ayudar

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen Día.

Tu error es que al intentar inicializar tu array con el for es incorrecto, no se puede acceder  de esa forma.

Tu primer ejemplo lo inicializas con dos ítems de TaxOutputType, dentro de las llaves, lo cual es correcto, por lo que te generara un array de dos ítems.

En el segundo ejemplo lo que tienes que hacer es declarar tu array de dos items, y posterior en el for acceder a cada item y asignarle su valor.

```
TaxOutputType[] taxexOutputs = new TaxOutputType[2];

for (int i=0; i< 2; i++) {
    taxexOutputs[i] = new TaxOutputType
    {
        TaxTypeCode = TacTypeCodeType.Item03,
        TaxRate = (double)_porcentaje_igic[0],
        TaxableBase = tacableBase,
        TaxAmount = taxAmount
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido de gran utilidad